# Existence of tunnel systems in 3-manifolds

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $M$ be a compact 3-manifold and $L \subset M$ a link.  A tunnel system for $L$ is a set $T = \{ t_1,...,t_n\}$ of embedded arcs in $M$ with endpoints on $L$ such that after removing an open regular neighborhood of $L \cup T$ from $M$ we obtain a handlebody.  For $M = S^3$ if we take a projection of $L$ then we can just add tunnels at each of the crossings in order to obtain a tunnel system.

How do we prove that tunnel systems exist in general?

Comment: An equivalent way to define tunnel number is to use Heegaard splittings. Moise in 1952 proved that ever 3-manifold has a Heegaard splitting, which then gives you the same result.  See [here](http://tunnel-knot.sakura.ne.jp/T-G-H.pdf) for more information.